# Erro ao acessar Webcam.js - Error: Webcam is not loaded yet

Tags: java, primefaces, glassfish

Estou recebendo este erro ao acessar a `Webcam.js`

> Error: Webcam is not loaded yet

Já estou usando conexão segura mais o erro persiste.
Estou usando `Primefaces`, o componente `photocam`.
Servidor de aplicação utilizado é o `Payara` - derivado do `GlassFish`.

Minha View

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
<p:photoCam style="margin: 0 auto;" widgetVar="pc" update="cod" listener="#{vendaControle.oncapture}" /> 
<p:poll interval="1" oncomplete="PF('pc').capture()"/>
```

Meu Controller

```
public void oncapture(CaptureEvent captureEvent) {
        try {
            if (captureEvent != null) {
                Result result = null;
                BufferedImage image = null;

                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(captureEvent.getData());

                image = ImageIO.read(in);

                LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
                BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

                result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
                if (result != null) {
                    setCodBarras(result.getText());
                    System.out.println("Código de Barras: " + codBarras);
                }
            }
        } catch (NotFoundException ex) {
            // fall thru, it means there is no QR code in image
        } catch (ReaderException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image: Erro]